# handleWatchKitExtensionRequest not responding to openParentApplication when iphone app in inactive state

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

Hi i'm developing app for watchkit map, so  trying to get user's current location from parent app(iPhone) this funtionality is working fine when parent app(iPhone) running on backround state, but not working when iphone app in inActive state(app not runs in background state&foreground state), i couldn't able to find a reason about that, so can anyone help me to fix the issue.

Comment: Can you add code on how you are retrieving the user's location? Are you using the openParent call?